# Remove Price attribute from a custom product type

Tags: product, adminhtml, product-attribute

I have created **a new product type that doesn't need a price attribute** so I would like to hide the tab in the backend in a similar way as Grouped product are.

**How can I accomplish this ?**

Comment: This is by predefine attributes in Magento you can not delete and change this attribute. so u can not do this

Comment: I found out the solution thx

Answer (score 1):

The attribute tabs are displayed only if the group tab contains any attribute.

see `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs::_prepareLayout()`

```
if (count($attributes)==0) {
                    continue;
                }
```

So there is nothing special here: if you look at the prices attribute you will see they are not assigned to the `grouped products` that is why the tab is not displayed.

You can change the `apply_to` values of any of the product attributes in 2 way: manually or using an installer script.

*Example installer script*:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$price_attributes = array(
    'group_price',
    'msrp_display_actual_price_type',
    'price',
    'special_price',
    'tier_price',
    'msrp_enabled',
    'msrp',
);

foreach ($price_attributes as $attribute_code) {
    $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code, 'apply_to', 'simple,configurable,virtual');
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

**Note:**
This will also have impact on frontend so you need to modify price.html and price index according to your needs