# How to hide Price tab in admin under creating or editing products?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I have a problem on hiding or removing the price tab in admin where you create or edit product since I don't have to type any price. Can you help me about this? or do you have any suggestions?

Here is the related question ([Remove Price attribute from a custom product type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64382/remove-price-attribute-from-a-custom-product-type)) but I don't really know what it means and the solution.

Thanks,

Nino

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve it by changing it to User Define instead of System attribute.